# How to translate a text for a toast message

Tags: admin-on-rest

I want to use translation for a toast message. How can I do it?
See the code below:

```
fetch(request).then(response => {
        if (response.status < 200 || response.status > 300) {
          // throw new Error(response.statusText);
        } // if
        return response.json();
      }).then (({token, message}) => {
        if (token) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        } else {
          throw new Error((translate('pos.search')));
        } // else
      });
```

Comment: Where is this code executed ? Inside a component ?

Comment: In the auth client